# SQL query to select records where date field is certain week number

Tags: ms-access, jet

I have no own "script syntax" for my application. It is designed for creating simple reports from a Microsoft Access Database using JET. Here is a simple example:

```
REQUIRES "Min number of away talks:" AS $iMinNumAwayTalks
LOOP FROM "Home Talks" NODATERANGE WHERE "Last Given" ISMOREOREQUAL "$Today"  SORTBY "Last Given"
    SHORTDATE_FIELD "Last Given"
    TAB =5>
    TEXT "Week: "
    VARIABLE_FIELD "Last Given" "$iWeekNo#CUSTOMDATE[%W]"
    TEXT "$iWeekNo"
    $iAwayTalkCount = 0
    LOOP FROM "Away Talks" NODATERANGE WHERE "Talk Date" ISMOREOREQUAL "$Today"  SORTBY "Talk Date"
        VARIABLE_FIELD "Talk Date" "$iAwayWeekNo#CUSTOMDATE[%W]"
        IF "$iAwayWeekNo" IS "$iWeekNo"
            $iAwayTalkCount = $iAwayTalkCount + 1
        END_IF
    END_LOOP
    TAB =10>
    TEXT "# Away: "
    TEXT "$iAwayTalkCount"
    TAB =15>
    TEXT "$iMinNumAwayTalks"
    TEXT " Exceed? "
    IF "$iAwayTalkCount" ISMORE "$iMinNumAwayTalks"
        TEXT "Yes"
    END_IF
    IF "$iAwayTalkCount" ISLESSOREQUAL "$iMinNumAwayTalks"
        TEXT "No"
    END_IF
    EOL
END_LOOP
```

It is basically looking at two tables to work out how many records have the same **Week Number** (beginning **Monday**) for the specified fields.

My question relates to this query I have used:

```
LOOP FROM "Away Talks" NODATERANGE WHERE "Talk Date" ISMOREOREQUAL "$Today"  SORTBY "Talk Date"
```

The downside with this query is that is is selecting all records greater than today and then I have to examine each record to see if the "Talk Date" field has the same week number.

[image: Results]

Now, my script syntax supports raw SQL loops too. So is it possible using a raw Microsoft Access JET SQL query to:

Select all **Away Talks** where the **Talk Date** field is **Week X** (where Week is week starting **Monday**)?

I have tried to do a manual test in Access 2016 with the criteria:

```
SELECT [Away Talks].[Talk Date]
FROM [Away Talks]
WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Talk Date],'vbMonday')=45));
```

But I have an error:

[image: Access Error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to filter on both _year_ and _week_ as week 01 and 52/53 may cross calendar boundaries. For example, week 2019-01 spans 2018-12-31 to 2019-01-06. Also, there is no week 00.

Comment: @Gustav Ah, these values are from my MFC program and it returns 0 to 51. So I must add 1 to those results. Thanks. And I thought about the year too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You provide `vbMonday` in your query as a string literal (`'vbMonday'`), instead of a numeric value.

Unfortunately you can't use the VBA constant `vbMonday` in a query, so you would have to use its numeric equivalent: `2`

To find out this numeric value yourself you can enter `?vbMonday` in the VBEs immediate window, or open the 'Object Browser' window for example by pressing `F2` in the VBE.
There you could search for `vbMonday` and see it's numeric value at the bottom of the window.

Comment: I saw the value of 2 in the help where it listed the parameters. When I get home I will give your suggestion a try. Thank you.

Comment: Right, the documentation/help also is a good source of information. Always. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria in the query design window is supplying a week number not a date so you need to create the week no field to apply the criteria to - try pasting your code into the SQL query editor

```
SELECT [Away Talks].[Talk Date]
FROM [Away Talks]
WHERE ((DatePart('ww',[Talk Date], 2)=45));
```

[image: See below]

Comment: My criteria was correct. The field itself is the date and I was extracting the week number from it and comparing it against a specific week number for test purposes. I suggest this answer is deleted and it is not correct. The reason was as stated in the other answer. Ironically in your example you have done it right and used `2` instead of `vbMonday` anyway. That is all it was.

Comment: Your criteria and SQL was correct - But in the picture posted of the design window you are applying the criteria to the date field, not the calculated week value. If you open the query editor with your correct SQL you will see it is applied in a different way in the query view. That is why you got the Data Mismatch - which was your original question.

Comment: Ah, yes, I did notice this when I went from the corrected SQL view to the design view. So I will up-vote your answer. Thank you.